# C# Unable to input decimal numbers

Tags: c#, math

I'm doing a small task for UNI and I can't find the answer to this problem:

Inputting liner numbers works fine but when trying to insert decimal numbers in the console  errors pop up

The code:

```
using System;

namespace Circle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Radius R = ");
            String radius = Console.ReadLine();
            Double num1 = 3.1415926;
            Double num2 = Int32.Parse(radius);
            Double RLG = num2 * 2 * num1;
            Double RL = Math.Pow(num2, 2) * num1;
            Double LL = Math.Pow(num2, 2) * 4 * num1;
            Double LT = Math.Pow(num2, 3) * 4 * num1 / 3;

            Console.WriteLine("circle line length " + CLL);
            Console.WriteLine("circle surface size " + CSS);
            Console.WriteLine("sphere surface size " + SSS);
            Console.WriteLine("sphere volume " + SV);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you go to the doctor, do you say "I feel sick", or do you explain precisely what symptoms you're experiencing? Stack Overflow is the same as your doctor. Instead of saying "an error pops up", please describe **exactly** what happens, including the text of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So initially there are a few problems with your code.

On this line below, you're parsing 'radius' as an `int` and saving it to a `Double` variable. You should use `Double.Parse` if you want a Double value.

```
Double num2 = Int32.Parse(radius);
```

Then in the code below, you're referencing variables which do not exist.

```
Console.WriteLine("circle line length " + CLL);
Console.WriteLine("circle surface size " + CSS);
Console.WriteLine("sphere surface size " + SSS);
Console.WriteLine("sphere volume " + SV);
```

If you changed the variables, to the below and Double.Parse'd ...

```
Console.WriteLine("RLG = " + RLG);
Console.WriteLine("RL = " + RL);
Console.WriteLine("LL = " + LL);
Console.WriteLine("LT = " + LT);
```

You would get the following output ...

```
RLG = 165.373434464
RL = 2176.31439754624
LL = 8705.25759018496
LT = 76374.12659122272
```